# P5.js a-tag click event does not work on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, canvas, mobile, p5.js

I have a problem with p5.js, e.g. i have this html-body:

```
<a href="www.google.de">go to google</a>
<div id=sketch-holder></div>
```

and simply draw a circle with p5.js:

```
function setup() {
canvas = createCanvas(200, 200);
canvas.parent('sketch-holder');
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    fill(100);
    ellipse(100, 100, 50, 50);
}
```

On every desktop i can click on the a-tag "go to google" and get to google.
On mobile devices (tested with ios and samsung-android) p5.js get the events, but no redirect is called. It is just not working.

Can anybody tell me why, and how to avoid this bug?

Comment: I'm not sure that this has anything to do with p5.js, do you have any CSS on the page? Can you try turning the device landscape to see if that works?

Comment: I agree with Michael. It doesn't make sense to expect P5.js to "get the events" of an external `a` tag without any connecting code. Please post a [mcve] and a link to a page that's exhibiting this behavior. Try removing P5.js to see what happens.

Comment: You were right, it really was some css-problem, thank you!